# trigonometry mountain elevation problem

Tags: trigonometry

> At the foot of a mountain the elevation of its summit is $45^{\circ}$. After ascending $1000\mathrm{m}$ towards mountain up a slope of $30^{\circ}$ inclination, the elevation is found to $60^{\circ}$. Find the height of mountain?

Answer (score 3):

Here I am attaching the picture. Hope you'll be able to solve now.
[image]

Here in figure AB is mountain.

Comment: Nice diagram, out of interest, how do you draw one these diagrams on stack exchange?

Comment: Also, I'm wondering whether CE should be 1000m in this diagram (instead of CD-not very clear from the question)?

Comment: Yes ! john CE would be 1000 m, mistakenly i wrote CD 1000 m

Answer (score 0):

Since
$\angle ACD
=45
$,
$AB = CB$.

Since
$\angle ECD = 30$,
$ED = \frac12 CE
= 500
$
and
$CD = 500\sqrt{3}$.

Label the point
between $A$ and $E$
as $F$.
Then
$AE = 2EF$
and
$AF = EF\sqrt{3}$.

Therefore
$AB = 500+EF\sqrt{3}$.

But
$AB = CB
=CD+DB
=500\sqrt{3}+EF
$.

Therefore
$500+EF\sqrt{3}
=500\sqrt{3}+EF
$
or
$EF = 500$.

Therefore
$AB = CB = 1500$.